# LinkedIn access token is null when using Android SDK

Tags: android, linkedin-api

```
  public void signInWithLinkedIn(View view){
        LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).init(this, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthSuccess() {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success" + LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSession().getAccessToken().getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("SESSION", Boolean.toString(LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSession().isValid()));
                //fetchBasicProfileData();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed " + error.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, true);

        // After complete authentication start new HomePage Activity
    }
```

The block of code in `onAuthSuccess` got executed but getSession returns null AND most importantly the access token is null, making me unable to call other linkedin APIs. This happens only recently. Am I doing it correctly?

Updated:- One more thing it generally happens with few specific LinkedIn Ids and working fine with rest of the id.

Comment: Any update on this ?

Answer (score 3):

LinkedIn is updating its android sdk  and they deprecate several methods.They started doing this from this week, I also got the same problem.You should use javascript api's to authenticate user rather than using linkedin android sdk.We fixed ur problem the same way.

Comment: Hi, @Asad 
Please tell me, how to do that using javascript in detail.

Comment: @ChetanKumarPatel currenly the project is close but you can get a help from this link https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api